# When would I use the following interrogatives of quantity: 몇, 얼마나 and 얼마?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-request

I'm a French really really beginner Korean learner, but I'm trying to add more content to the [French Korean wikibook](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cor%C3%A9en).

At this point, I'm working on the interrogative words, but I find the question examples a little too difficult or sometimes ambiguous.

For example regarding time should you use 몇 or 얼마나 ? Which kind of phrases would use which one ?

is 얼마 used only with currency ?

Examples of some simple phrases would be helpful.

Comment: Some discussion in comments [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59668/discussion-on-question-by-lumiweb-when-would-i-use-the-following-interrogatives).

Comment: Post-Scriptum : if you want to help with the [English wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Korean) there is a lot of work to do ^^

Answer (score 2):

몇 is 'What' and 얼마 is 'How (long, far, much,...)'.

지금 몇 시냐? -> What time is it now?

시간이 얼마나 걸리냐? -> How long does it take?

And 얼마 can use anything can measure.

여기서 얼마나 멀어? -> How far is it from here?

(이거) 얼마에요? -> How much is it?